# Material does not appear in Unity

Tags: materials, unity, .fbx

The texture that I made in Blender on Object, doesn't appear in Unity

eg.
World Ugliest Dog In Blender:
[image: World Ugliest Dog In Blender:]

The same in Unity:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you using fbx in the process? If yes make sure you are embeding doge textures within the fbx. You have to set this in export options:
[image]

Comment: Yeah, it is in FBX, and I tried what you suggested me, but it did not work